# $q 'finally' not working in IE8

Tags: angularjs, q

Angular 1.2 replaced `always` with `finally` on promises.

So what was once this:

```
$http.get('/myurl').always(handler);
```

Now needs to be this:

```
$http.get('/myurl').finally(handler);
```

But I am getting the error "expected identifier" in IE8. How can I make this work in IE8?

Comment: This is [**the same issue with `catch`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105089/angular-q-catch-method-fails-in-ie8).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found it: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f078762d48d0d5d9796dcdf2cb0241198677582c

`$http.get('/myurl')["finally"](handler);`

Comment: please note that `.catch()` also as to be wrapped for IE8 `["catch"](eventHandler)`

Comment: I like how you answered your own question!